# Bind mount not visible when created from a CGI script in Apache

Tags: linux, apache, centos7

My application allows the user to bind mount a source directory to a target mount point. This is all working correctly except the mount does not exist outside the process that corrected it.

I have boiled down the issue to a very simple script.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""
echo ""

echo "<p>Hello</p>"

echo "<p>Results from pid #{$$}:</p>"
echo "<ul>"
  c="sudo mkdir /shares/target"
  echo "<li>Executed '$c', Results: " $(eval $c) "</li>"

  c="sudo mount --bind /root/source /shares/target"
  echo "<li>Executed '$c', Results: " $(eval $c) "</li>"

  c="sudo mount | grep shares"
  echo "<li>Executed '$c', Results: " $(eval $c) "</li>"

  c="sudo cat /proc/mounts | grep shares"
  echo "<li>Executed '$c', Results: " $(eval $c) "</li>"
echo "</ul>"
```

The first two commands create a mount point and execute the mount. The last two commands verify the result. The script executes without issue. However, the mount is not visible or available in a separate shell process. Executing the last two commands in a separate shell does not show the mount being available. If I attempt to execute "rm -rf /shares/target" I get "rm: cannot remove '/shares/target/': Device or resource busy”. Executing "losf | grep /shares/target" generates no output. In a seperate shell I have switch to the apache user but the mount is still not available. I have verified the apache process is not in a chroot by logging the output of "ls /proc/$$/root". It points to "/".

I am running:

- Apache 2.4.6
- CentOS 7
- httpd-2.4.6-31.el7.centos.1.x86_64
- httpd-tools-2.4.6-31.el7.centos.1.x86_64

I turned logging to debug but the error_log indicates nothing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This behavior is due to the following line in the `httpd.service` systemd unit:

```
PrivateTmp=true
```

From the `systemd.exec(5)` man page:

```
   PrivateTmp=
       Takes a boolean argument. If true, sets up a new file
       system namespace for the executed processes and mounts
       private /tmp and /var/tmp directories inside it that is not
       shared by processes outside of the namespace.
       [...]
       Note that using this setting will disconnect propagation of
       mounts from the service to the host (propagation in the
       opposite direction continues to work). This means that this
       setting may not be used for services which shall be able to
       install mount points in the main mount namespace.
```

In other words, mounts made by `httpd` and child processes will not be
visible to other processes on your host.

The `PrivateTmp` directive is useful from a security perspective, as described [here](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/security.html):

> /tmp traditionally has been a shared space for all local services and
>   users. Over the years it has been a major source of security problems
>   for a multitude of services. Symlink attacks and DoS vulnerabilities
>   due to guessable /tmp temporary files are common. By isolating the
>   service's /tmp from the rest of the host, such vulnerabilities become
>   moot.

You can safely remove the `PrivateTmp` directive from the unit file (well, don't actually modify the unit file -- create a new one at `/etc/systemd/system/httpd.service`, then `systemctl daemon-reload`, then `systemctl restart httpd`).